# Computing inverse of Covariance Matrix is resulting in 'Inf'

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance

I have Computed the Covariance Matrix in Matlab for one of my program. Then eventually i want to calculate the Mahalanobis Distance, which will need the Inverse of the same.

But the entries in my Covariance matrix are very small and many are zeros.

The message that i get when inverse is tried  to be found is :

> Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.

what is the meaning of all this? how can i proceed further? Please suggest me.

regards

Prashanth

Comment: When a matrix is `singular`, that means the condition number is **very high**.  What it means is that your matrix is very sensitive to small changes in its elements.  Should you use this for any calculations, a small change in any of its elements results in an output that is very different compared to the previous output.  Basically, your matrix is ill-defined. Are you sure you computed the distances correctly? Did you choose the right features? Are you sure you pre-processed them properly? Without further context in how you came up with this matrix, we can't really help you further.

Comment: i will work on that part again. as you said, then will come with any other doubts. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a matrix is `singular` it means that it is non invertible. The determinant is 0 which means that there are at least 2 rows in the matrix that is linear dependent, eg `[0.5,0.5;0.5,0.5]` or `[1,0;0,0]`. However, are you sure that the covariance matrix is calculated correctly? There is highly unlikely that the covariance matrix should have 2 linearly dependent rows, since the covariance for a set of samples should have a high covariance with itself. However, 2 almost similar processes may cause this issue. Try:

```
a = randn(1000,1);
b = randn(1000,1);
covAB = cov(a,b);
covAA = cov(a,a);
covAB^-1
covAA^-1
```